# Does Anyone know of a Canadian Weather data provider?

Tags: service, web, weather, weather-api

I'm looking for a weather data provider for Canada that is similar to Noaa's NDFD SOAP Service. (i.e. a real-time weather data for Canada)

I am aware of http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/business/index_e.html

However, I would prefer a Web Service.

Is anyone aware of such a Web Service or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Weatherundergound (http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/) easy to use and covers the world.